# Probability percentages more than 100%

Tags: probability, percentages

## The Question

"Airlines monitor the causes of flights arriving late. A total of 75% of flights are late because of weather, while 35% of flights are late because of ground operations. A full 15% of flights are late because of weather and ground operations. What is the probability that a flight arrives late because of weather or ground operations? (2 numbers behind decimal, example: 0.34)"

## The *Supposed* Solution

My friend just did this: $0.75+0.35-0.15=0.95$

## My Question

This may be an overcomplication, but I just feel that there is something wrong with this question. How is it possible for a portion, represented by percentages, to total larger than 100%? Is it just me or is the question mistaken?

Comment: $95<100$ , where does more than 100% occur here ?

Comment: I think he means why lateness for Weather OR Ground traffic adds up to $110%$ initially - OP please word your question more clearly

Comment: The intermediate result (110%) has no meaning , it is not the final result , not the correct probability (or proportion). Of course , probabilities are always in the range $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no errors in the question. Look at this Venn representation of your problem

[image]

where the red circle is the event: late due to weather conditions and the blue one is the event: late for Ground operations

What is the probability that an airplane arrives late ONLY for weather conditions? Obviously it is not 75% because this probability does not exclude to have both bad weather conditions AND ground operations too...